# Javascript: Deeply Changing a const array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a problem that is expecting a const array to deeply equal a new set of values.

How would I go about this?

Instructions: Iterate through the array and multiply a number by 10 if it is greater than or equal to 5.

What I have:

```
const timesTenIfOverFive = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];


for(var i = 0; i < timesTenIfOverFive.length; i++){
if (timesTenIfOverFive[i] >= 5) {
console.log(timesTenIfOverFive[i]*10); 
} else console.log(timesTenIfOverFive[i]);
} 

// console.log(timesTenIfOverFive); // -> should print [230, 90, 110, 2, 100, 60]
```

Comment: *equal a new set of values* : `const result = timesTenIfOverFive.map(e => e >= 5 ? e * 10 : e)`

Comment: ‘const’ doesn’t give an immutable value, it gives an immutable assignment, with which you cannnot reassign the variable, but still able to manipulate non-primitive data structure (object, array, etc)

Answer (score 1):

`const` only means that the variable in question can't be *reassigned* - you can still mutate it. (Non-primitives, like objects and arrays, can be mutated.) The question is asking you to iterate over the array and mutate it, which is pretty easy with a `for` loop or `forEach` - on each iteration, assign the result to `timesTenIfOverFive[i]`:

```js
const timesTenIfOverFive = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];
for(var i = 0; i < timesTenIfOverFive.length; i++){
  if (timesTenIfOverFive[i] >= 5) {
    timesTenIfOverFive[i] *= 10;
  }
}
console.log(timesTenIfOverFive);
```